# Resize a path in android canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have drawn an path in my canvas. On Single tap I want to resize the path. Say I want to make it double the original size.

I have tried [path.transform](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#transform%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) but it shifts the path to a different location in canvass. This is the code I used for that

```
Matrix translateMatrix = new Matrix();
translateMatrix.setTranslate(100,0);
p.transform(translateMatrix);
```

How can I resize a path in android?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have tried the solution provided by smitalm. Still the path was shifting its location. I have tried this way and it worked for me.

```
Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
RectF rectF = new RectF();
path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
scaleMatrix.setScale(1.25f, 1.25f,rectF.centerX(),rectF.centerY());
path.transform(scaleMatrix);
```

Comment: The rectF.centerX() and rectF.centerY() will help you to scale the path w.r.t its center position, 1.25f,1.25f  are (x and y axis to scale) ,, PS: FOR SCALE LARGE (x,y axis)= 1.001; FOR SCALE SMALL  (x,y axis) = 0.999;

Answer (score 5):

Havent done this by myself, but you should probably use

```
Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
scaleMatrix.setScale(sx,sy, px, py);
p.transform(scaleMatrix);
```

where `sx,sy` should be `2,2` in your case, if you want double size
and `px,py` should probably be `0.5,0.5` in your case

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your code. It is scaling but at the same time it shifts its position. I want to scale it on centre. How can I do that?

Comment: @Zach then you have to use setScale version that allows pivots, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
RectF bounds = new RectF();
path.computeBounds(bounds, true);
Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
scaleMatrix.setScale(scale_pathSX, scale_pathSY,
    bounds.centerX(),bounds.centerY());
path.transform(scaleMatrix);
```

The Bound.centerx and center Y will help you to scale the path to its center position, scale_pathSX and scale_pathSY is for how much you want to scale your path,
FOR SCALE LARGE
scale_pathSX and scalepathSy = 1.001;  FOR SCALE SMALL scale_pathSX and scalepathSy = 0.999;